Not able to select Blender shader nodes
Not able to select or move the shader nodes in shader page, whenever  LMB is pressed it shows an error saying "Nothing to erase". Not really sure if I have accidentally pressed any keyboard shortcuts.


press T key, you should see tool selection on the left, take a screenshot then. You probably have annotation eraser chosen instead of box select.

I corrected the case, because I have scripts for that making it extremely easy to do. Please don't use all capitals. Formatting the questions in a uniform readable manner will increase the chances of getting help quickly. All caps will only attract comments like this one or might even  get you unnecessary down-votes.

@MarkusvonBroady, thank you it worked

@MartynasŽiemys, thank you.

Apparently by accident (keyboard shortcut) you've switched active tool to the Annotation Eraser. The default tool is called the Selection Box, which you can choose in the Toolbar Menu , which you can open by pressing T or clicking/dragging small arrow in top-left corner:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
